# Upload camera captured image to web server

Tags: php, android, kotlin, camera

I developed an app to capture photo with camera and upload it, that second part of uploading is resulting to error. The camera captures and save to gallery successfully but not uploaded to web server. I am using kotlin language and volley library. The image saved in the gallery does not show up immediately, after closing the gallery app or waiting minutes then the captured image shows up.
So i think the error results when image is trying to upload.

MainActivity class

```
import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.StrictMode
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Base64
import android.util.Base64.encodeToString
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.livinglifetechway.quickpermissions_kotlin.runWithPermissions
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener  {


    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id){
            R.id.btnCamera ->{
                requestPermissions()

            }
            R.id.btnSend ->{
                uploadFile()

            }
        }

    }
    val url = "http:// 192.168.45.240/htdocs/upload.php"
    var imstr = ""
    var namafile = ""
    var fileUri = Uri.parse("")
    lateinit var mediaHelper:MediaHelper
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        try {
            val m = StrictMode ::class.java.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure")
            m.invoke(null)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        mediaHelper = MediaHelper()
        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(this)
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(this)


    }

    fun uploadFile(){
        val request = object : StringRequest(Method.POST,url,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                val jsonObject = JSONObject(response);
                val kode =jsonObject.getString("kode")
                if (kode.equals("000")){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"upload success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"upload fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener{ error ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }) {
            override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String>{
                val hm = HashMap<String, String>()
                hm.put("imstr",imstr)
                hm.put("namafile", namafile)
                return hm
            }
        }
        val q = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        q.add(request)
    }

    fun requestPermissions() = runWithPermissions(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA){
        fileUri = mediaHelper.getOutputMediaFileUri()
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,fileUri)
        startActivityForResult(intent,mediaHelper.getRcCamera())
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            if (requestCode == mediaHelper.getRcCamera()){
                imstr = mediaHelper.getBitmapToString(imv)
                namafile = mediaHelper.getMyFileName()
        }
    }

    fun methodWithPermissions() = runWithPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Camera and audio recording permissions granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Do the stuff with permissions safely
    }
}
```

MediaHelper class

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Base64
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ImageView
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class MediaHelper {
    var namaFile=""
    var fileUri = Uri.parse("")
    var RC_CAMERA = 100

    fun getMyFileName(): String{
        return this.namaFile
    }

    fun getRcCamera(): Int{
        return this.RC_CAMERA
    }

    private fun getOutputMediaFile(): File? {
        val mediaStorageDir = File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),
            "upload8"
        )
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists())
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e("mkdir", "directory available")
            }
        return File(mediaStorageDir.path + File.separator + namaFile)

    }
    fun getOutputMediaFileUri(): Uri{
        val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
        this.namaFile = "DC_${timeStamp}.jpg"
        this.fileUri = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile())
        return this.fileUri
    }

    fun bitmapToString(bmp: Bitmap) : String{
        val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,60,outputStream)
        val byteArray = outputStream.toByteArray()
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT)
    }

    fun getBitmapToString(imV: ImageView):String{
        var bmp:Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100,100,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.fileUri.path)
        val dim = 720
        if (bmp.height>bmp.width){
            bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,(bmp.width*dim).div(bmp.height),dim, true)
        }else{
            bmp  = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, dim, (bmp.height*dim).div(bmp.width), true)
        }
        imV.setImageBitmap(bmp)
        return bitmapToString(bmp)
        return ""
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id  'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.upload8"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    implementation 'com.github.quickpermissions:quickpermissions-kotlin:0.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

upload.php

```
<?php
    $imstr = $_POST['imstr'];
    $namaFile = $_POST[namaFile];
    $path = "images/";
    
    $respon = array();
    $respon['kode'] = '000';
    if(file_put_contents($path.$namaFile, base64_decode($imstr)) == false){
        $respon['kode'] = '111';
        echo json_encode($respon);
    }else{
        echo json_encode($respon);
    }   
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Is your PHP code receiving the information correctly? What is `$_POST[namafile]` without quotes around the array index? Is `namaFile` defined somewhere? Presumably in your dev environment the phone is on your LAN, to allow you to post to a non-routable IP address? So not going via the internet.

Comment: well i missed those quotes but added them and still get an error. Yes I use 'namafile' in the code as name of file. I use phone hotspot and connect the pc to it and another phone(where i install app and try image capture & upload).

Comment: What error do you get? Does your PHP execute at all? How far through does it get? What is in `$_POST` when you display it?

Comment: I get 'error' in the app that i defined as a result of upload fail. The php when executed in browser using xampp shows blank page.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the Android side of things. I can see that you check to see if the response code is "000" and that indicates success, or any other response indicates failure. But I can't see what instructs your code to indicate "error" - that seems to suggest that it isn't getting a response from the PHP code. Is the PHP even running? If you write to a log in your PHP code, is anything happening?

Comment: am redoing it, will give feedback. Thanks